# how to apply authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Can any one tell me how to solve the following scenario in Asp.net application.

I have an asp.net application which has 3 pages.Some user should allow to view some pages.For ex, user 1 should see page 1 but not page 2.
In web.config file, under App_settings, I have a key-value(user1 - 0) if the value is 0 then he should allow to view the page other wise, he should not allow to view the page.

So, the problem is based on app_setting value, I need to restrict or allow the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stop using the AppSetting and use the membership/role provider

http://odetocode.com/articles/427.aspx